# jQuery click function exception

Tags: jquery

I am displaying a container `<div class="expand">` that - when clicked on - expands the `section` below it:

HTML:

```
<div class="expand">
    <div class="container1">
         <div class="container2">
             <a class="view">View</a>
             <a class="download">Download</a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="hidden">
...
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.expand').click(function () {

   var $this = $(this);
   $this.next().show();

});
```

As you can see, there also a "Download" button as a child element of the `<div class="expand">`. This Download button should be the only element in this very container that does not trigger the said section to be shown.

So I would like to do something like this:

```
$('.expand').not(".download").click(function () {
...
});
```

or

```
$('.expand').except(".download").click(function () {
...
});
```

Comment: why not this `$('.download').click(function () {`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I would like the whole <div class="expand"> container EXCEPT FOR the <a class="download"> button to trigger the function.

Comment: Do you want the event to *not* fire on click of `download`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include a function at the end of the code:

It's here: `event.stopPropagation()`

Please try, it will work!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) as well:

```
$('.download').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}

$('.expand').click(function () {
    ...
});
```

This will stop the event from moving up in the DOM to parents, and triggering their event handlers as well.

Answer (score 3):

use **e.target** to check clicked element is download or not

```
$('.expand').click(function (e) {

    if (!$(e.target).is(".download")) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next().show();
    }

});
```

Comment: just i posted .. i ll explain 2min

Comment: would make total sense to me, but it does not seem to work. It seems to keep the function from executing in the first place. Thanks though!

Comment: Then you have to use return     if ($(e.target).is(".download")) {
      return;
    }else{}

Answer (score 1):

you can add stoppropagation() function after your code.

```
$('.expand').click(function (event) {   var $this = $(this);   $this.next().show();
```

event.stopPropagation();
});

Answer (score 1):

You need `event.stopPropagation()`. This stops the event from bubbling or propagating to the children.

```
$('.expand').find(".download").click(function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation()
})
```